# Implementing an ANY filter on an underlying collection for a report

Tags: netsuite

I want to make a report showing all creditors that have at least one credit invoice. I know how to make some filters, but how could I create a filter that filters out all creditors that have not at least 1 invoice which is a credit invoice.

In SQL I would just inner join the invoice table based on whether an invoice is a credit invoice, but I am kind of new to NetSuite.

How can I perform this functionality in a NetSuite report?

Answer (score 0):

You can do a search on vendors joined to transactions. Your filters will be a standard filter and a summary filter.

For the Standard Filter:

- Filter = Transaction : Type
- Description = is Bill Credit

For the Summary Filter:

- Summary Type = Count
- Field = Transaction : Internal ID
- Description = is greater than 0